# How to select in range and print if no result on one of the items

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table which let's say for simplicity consists only of ids and names:

```
select * from mytable;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Test1 |
|  2 | Test3 |
|  3 | Test3 |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

I want to select ids in subset of the ids:

```
select * from mytable where id in (1 ,3, 88);
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Test1 |
|  3 | Test3 |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

As you see there is no 88 in the result. I want to flag it and print something like "NO".

I hope to get something like this:

```
select * from mytable where id in (1 ,3, 88, 99);
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Test1 |
|  3 | Test3 |
| 88 | NO    |
| 99 | NO    |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.20 sec)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
select num,coalesce(name,'No') as Name
from
(select 1 as num union all select 3 union all select 88 union all select 99 
)A left join mytable b on a.num=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The best long term solution here might be to just maintain a calendar table of all possible `id` value which you would expect using to search.  In lieu of this, we can use an inline subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    COALESCE(t2.name, 'NO') AS name
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    -- other numbers
    SELECT 88 UNION ALL
    -- more numbers
    SELECT 99
) t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t1.id IN (1, 3, 88, 99)
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

The strategy here is twofold.  First, we left join the calendar table to your table, retaining all `id` values in the full range.  Then, we restrict to only `id` values you want to see.  For those `id` values which do *not* appear in your table, the names would show up as `NULL`.